# Using IXMLDOMDocument and XPath to parse Dynamics 365 XML data

Tags: xml, xpath, vcl, delphi-10.2-tokyo, dynamics-crm-365

Continuing on from my other questions about consuming REST services from Dynamics 365, I found that by setting the *Accept* property of the *TRESTRequest* appropriately, I can get the odata query result as XML (since trying to parse the odata response itself was just an exercise in frustration at Delphi).

```
RESTRequest.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
```

Leads to this result (sorry for the heavy block of XML, but this is what I am dealing with, not some nice shallow easy to use XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="https://mycrm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">BookableResourceSet</title>
  <id>https://mycrm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/BookableResourceSet</id>
  <updated>2018-05-29T02:47:48Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="BookableResourceSet" href="BookableResourceSet" />
  <entry>
    <id>https://mycrm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')</id>
    <title type="text">John Smith</title>
    <updated>2018-05-29T02:47:48Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="BookableResource" href="BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/systemuser_bookableresource_UserId" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="systemuser_bookableresource_UserId" href="BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')/systemuser_bookableresource_UserId">
      <m:inline>
        <entry>
          <id>https://mycrm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet(guid'1648251b-9bff-e611-8107-c4346bc50748')</id>
          <title type="text">John Smith</title>
          <updated>2018-05-29T02:47:48Z</updated>
          <author>
            <name />
          </author>
          <link rel="edit" title="SystemUser" href="SystemUserSet(guid'1648251b-9bff-e611-8107-c4346bc50748')" />
          <category term="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.SystemUser" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
          <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
              <d:FirstName>John</d:FirstName>
              <d:TerritoryId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">c10a3010-0087-e711-8113-c4346bc540c4</d:Id>
                <d:LogicalName>territory</d:LogicalName>
                <d:Name>District 9</d:Name>
                <d:RowVersion m:null="true" />
              </d:TerritoryId>
              <d:int_StaffNumber>A111111</d:int_StaffNumber>
              <d:int_ServiceAreaId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid" m:null="true" />
                <d:LogicalName m:null="true" />
                <d:Name m:null="true" />
                <d:RowVersion m:null="true" />
              </d:int_ServiceAreaId>
              <d:int_Title m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue">
                <d:Value m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true" />
              </d:int_Title>
              <d:LastName>Smith</d:LastName>
            </m:properties>
          </content>
        </entry>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
    <category term="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.BookableResource" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:BookableResourceId m:type="Edm.Guid">f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71</d:BookableResourceId>
        <d:int_cmsobjectid m:null="true" />
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://mycrm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/BookableResourceSet(guid'5f7767db-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')</id>
    <title type="text">Joe Bloggs</title>
    <updated>2018-05-29T02:47:48Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
```

Originally I had done this:

```
  AXMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);

  AXMLDoc.LoadFromXML(AResponseContent);
  AXMLDoc.Active := true;

  ARootNode := AXMLDoc.DocumentElement;

  APropertyNode := ARootNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('m:properties');
```

Or a variation of, and considered looping through all the nodes to find the ones I wanted, but the *FindNodes* function only checks the immediate children, so I would need to write a recursive method to basically search through all the child nodes until I found the one I wanted. This led me to the *selectNodes* function, which can do this for me.

However, it was a game and a half just to find out how to even use that function, and after going through a number of examples that didn't work due to deprecated methods, I finally tried this:

```
  AXMLDOMDoc := TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory.CreateDOMDocument;

  AXMLDOMDoc.loadXML(AResponseContent);

  AXMLNodeList := AXMLDOMDoc.selectNodes('/feed/entry/link/m:inline/entry/content/m:properties');
```

But that gave me a **"reference to undeclared namespace prefix: m"** error, which then led me to a SO question/answer about setting the DOM document properties, so I ended up with a descendant class of the *TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory* in order to not have the *selectNodes* function throw the error by ensuring the namespaces are included.

```
  type
    TDynamics365XMLResponseDocument = class(TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory)
    public
      class function CreateDOMDocument: IXMLDOMDocument; override;
    end;

  class function TDynamics365XMLResponseDocument.CreateDOMDocument: IXMLDOMDocument;
  begin
    Result := inherited;

    AddDOMProperty('SelectionNamespaces',
                   'xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" '+
                   'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" '+
                     'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"');

    SetDOMProperties(Result as IXMLDOMDocument2);
  end;
```

So, what I am after is an *IXMLDOMNodeList* containing all the **"m:properties"** nodes, as they are the ones that actually contain the data I am after. To achieve this, I do what I did above, but create the document from the descendant factory class:

```
  // Because the XML back from Dynamics 365 contains namespaces, we need to specify the URI's for them as part
  // of the document factory

  AXMLDOMDoc := TDynamics365XMLResponseDocument.CreateDOMDocument;

  // Load the document with the raw XML

  AXMLDOMDoc.loadXML(AResponseContent);

  // Using a XPath query, get all the entry property nodes that have the data we need

  AXMLDOMNodeList := AXMLDOMDoc.selectNodes('//feed/entry/link/m:inline/entry/content/m:properties');
```

I no longer get namespace errors but the AXMLDOMNodeList is always empty. I tried with a number of different query values, and they all return a list of 0 items, so it seems like the *selectNodes* of the *IXMLDOMDocument* isn't working, and I can't step into the source code to see why as the interfaces are just generated from a Microsoft type library.

Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong? Or a better way to do this?